# C++ operator ==, is it important to check self equality?

Tags: c++, operator-overloading

Foe example we heve

```
bool Foo::operator==(const Foo& other) {
  return bar == other.bar;
}
```

Is it important to chek is it the same object like this?

```
bool Foo::operator==(const Foo& other) {
if (this == &other) {
return true;
}
  return bar == other.bar;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If there are a lot of comparisons to make, then the check for self equality may speed up execution.  In this case, the code should be profiled to see how much time is saved when comparing the same object, versus the time taken up (wasted) when comparing separate variables.

Answer (score 0):

This could, conceivably, make comparisons that involve the same object a bit faster, at the cost of slowing down comparisons of distinct objects. In almost all situations this would be a net loss.

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't make any sense for you to check twice in the code you have above. However, in some cases when you are working with dynamic memory where things can change quickly, this can be beneficial. For the code you have, the first block of code is sufficient.